# Does Dreamweaver support Java?

Tags: java, dreamweaver

Is it possible to program java in Dreamweaver? I figure it would be a plugin but I would like to be able to do that instead of Netbeans because I like working in Dreamweaver better for some reason.

**Edit:** Just a note, this was just an idea that popped in my head. I wanted to know if you could just as a friendly question and I find this can be helpful to a few people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dreamweaver does not support Java compilation.

Dreamweaver supports web related technologies such as HTML, CSS and Javascript

Comment: That is what I thought. It was just an idea that popped in my mind

Comment: Don't feel like you have to use Netbeans for java, you could try Eclipse

Comment: Ya, I can't get Eclipse to work and haven't really bothered to figure out why.

Comment: @b2550 download, start, done? There is kind of nothing you have to do (besides having Java installed)

Comment: @zapl It's fine, I don't mind Netbeans, I just wanted to use Dreamweaver if it was possible. I don't really want Eclipse even if the fix is super easy (which it is).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look http://www.jsftoolbox.com/ is one way to achive what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the official site:**
Programming languages supported by Dreamweaver
In addition to text-editing capabilities, Adobe Dreamweaver provides various features, such as code hints, to help you code in the following languages:

**HTML, PHP, CSS and JavaScript.**
**Other languages**, such as Perl, **are not supported by the language-specific coding features in Dreamweaver**; for example, you can create and edit Perl files, but code hints don’t apply to that language.

So, in base, and for all newbies that can read this thread, you can program every language with every IDE (you can even use windows notepad), but you're getting code hints (AKA intellisense) only on supported languages for each IDE (each ide that support code hints, obviously).

It could be great for dreamweaver to support Java for JSP, C#, Ruby, Phyton... appart from front end + php, with official plug-ins, but at the moment it does not.

I recommend you **IntelliJ Idea** *by Jet Brains* **for java programming** as i tried the uggly net-beans, the buggy and seemly half-abandoned eclipse and IntelliJ and this last one is the best for me, give it a try! (you can get free license if you're a student).